# Get Cross sell items in cart page Programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, cross-sells

I am trying to get cross sell products in cart page programmatically.

Below code i have used in layout/**checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Customcross" name="cross.custom.details" after="-" template="Vendor_Module::cart/cart_products.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

So I need to write one function in my Block file that should return cross sell items.

Right now i am using like below in block file.

```
 namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
 use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
 use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
 class Customcross extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
protected $_storeManager;    
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_coreRegistry;  
protected $_urlInterface;
protected $_productloader;  
protected $_productRepository; 
protected $_productData; 
protected $_itemCollection;
protected $_catalogConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productData,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;  
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_productData = $productData;
    $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCurrencySymbol() {
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();
}


public function getBasetUrl() {
   return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
}

public function getCurrentUrl() {

return $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
}

public function getStore()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
}

public function getProductData($productId)
{
    $productObj = $this->_productData->load($productId);        
    return $productObj;

} 
protected function _prepareData()
{
    $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getCrossSellProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        $this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes()
    )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

    $this->_itemCollection->load();

    foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
        $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
    }

    return $this;
}
 public function getItems()
 {
     return $this->_itemCollection;
 }
}
```

Anyone help me. How to get the cross sell items like this.

Comment: cross-sell products by default shows on cart page. why you need to do this again?

Comment: Yes, default will show, but I am trying to get programmatically with some custom design in cart page, so can we get like I requested? Or should use default only?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, you have many typo mistakes in the code. Like **`use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;`** should be **`use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;`**.

Comment: If you are using **`use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`** in your code, you should inject this class in your constructor.

Comment: okay, so the change from  use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct; to use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct; will be fine or any class i need to inject?

Comment: Although I have not tested it, the rest of the code seems fine. What problem are you facing now?

Comment: It is returning empty, cross sell products are not returned in my file

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but perhaps you can do something similar to vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Crosssell.php `_prepareData()` function:

```
public function getItems()
{
   $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

    return $product->getCrossSellProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        $this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes()
    )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();
}
```

Comment: Not cleared with the answer, can you pls update full block class code?

Comment: We should get from quote  I think instead of current product, because can be many products in cart.

Comment: Hi @Sveta, can you update me full code of clock file

Comment: Tried your code, that didn't work for me

Comment: Please try adding \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig to your constructor.

Comment: Yes, @Sveta added, but still i am not getting results, updated my block file code

Comment: Are you calling the $this->_prepareData(); before calling the getItems() function?

Comment: No, _prepareData i am not calling anywhere, only i am calling getItems() function in my template file

Comment: Try adding the $this->_prepareData(); at the end of your constructor and see if that helps

Comment: end of constructor that is  after parent::__construct($context);?

Answer (score 0):

I have done to create cross cell products in cart page display only for two products.

Path: **Vendor/ModuleName/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

path: **Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Cart\Crosssell" />
</config>
```

path: **Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
     </module>
</config>
```

path: **Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Cart;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock as StockHelper;

class Crosssell extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory $productLinkFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\RelatedProducts $itemRelationsList,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutSession,
            $productVisibility,
            $productLinkFactory,
            $itemRelationsList,
            $stockHelper,
            $data
        );

        $this->_maxItemCount = 2; // here you can set product display limit
    }
}
```

It is working for me, I hope to work for all

Answer (score 0):

```
 parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutSession,
            $productVisibility,
            $productLinkFactory,
            $itemRelationsList,
            $stockHelper,
            $data
        )
```